# Ubuntu upstart won't start program due to log file creation failure

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions, upstart

I have an upstart script as follows.

```
#!upstart
description "example site services"
author "Peter"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn

script
echo $$ > /var/run/website.pid
exec /etc/nginx/website 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
echo "[Fri Sep 11 02:04:39 UTC 2015] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/website.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
rm /var/run/website.pid
echo "[2015-09-11T02:04:39.444Z] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/website.sys.log
end script
```

This should automatically start the `Nginx` website.

However, in the startup log I get this message.

```
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: cannot create /var/log/website.sys.log: Read-only file system
```

I have tried changing the permissions on this file. Its currently `root root` with both `rw` permissions. It is still not working.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root      root       1506 Sep 27 21:39 website.sys.log
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but found a solution which worked for me.

It was to not specify the log location.

I have changed

```
echo "[Fri Sep 11 02:04:39 UTC 2015] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/website.sys.log
```

to

```
echo "[Fri Sep 11 02:04:39 UTC 2015] (sys) Starting"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is probably off-topic here, `Read-only file system` means that you are starting that service too early in the boot sequence, when root filesystem has not been yet (re)mounted read-write. You should probably change

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
```

to something more appropriate, like

```
start on local-filesystems
stop on <whatever>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give your solution a go.